# Сохранить изображение, которое пользователь отправил боту

Tags: telegram-bot

Требуется сохранить изображение, которое пользователь отправил боту.
Насколько я понял требуется получить file_id и использовать getFile, но не могу разобраться(

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это реализовать?

*с pyTelegramBotAPI знаком совсем недавно*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['document'])
def handle_docs_photo(message):
try:
    chat_id = message.chat.id

    file_info = bot.get_file(message.document.file_id)
    downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)

    src = 'C:/Python/Project/tg_bot/files/received/' + message.document.file_name;
    with open(src, 'wb') as new_file:
        new_file.write(downloaded_file)

    bot.reply_to(message, "Пожалуй, я сохраню это")
except Exception as e:
    bot.reply_to(message, e)
```

Принятие всех типов файлов, сохранение в указанную директорию и ответ от бота в виде цитаты последнего сообщения и подписи "Пожалуй, я сохраню это"

UPD:

если несколько файлов, в т.ч. разных типов:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo', 'document'])
def handler_file(message):
    from pathlib import Path
    Path(f'files/{message.chat.id}/').mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    if message.content_type == 'photo':
        file_info = bot.get_file(message.photo[len(message.photo) - 1].file_id)
        downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)
        src = f'files/{message.chat.id}/' + file_info.file_path.replace('photos/', '')
        with open(src, 'wb') as new_file:
            new_file.write(downloaded_file)

    elif message.content_type == 'document':
        file_info = bot.get_file(message.document.file_id)
        downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)
        src = f'files/{message.chat.id}/' + message.document.file_name
        with open(src, 'wb') as new_file:
            new_file.write(downloaded_file)
```

Comment: у меня ошибка AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'file_id'

Answer (score 5):

Попробовал код выше, но для фото он не подходит. Модифицировав код получил следующее.

```
file_info = bot.get_file(message.photo[0].file_id)
downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)

src = filepath + message.photo[0].file_id
with open(src, 'wb') as new_file:
    new_file.write(downloaded_file)
```

Answer (score 4):

Может кому понадобится.

```py
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
def handle_docs_photo(message):

    try:


        file_info = bot.get_file(message.photo[len(message.photo)-1].file_id)
        downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)

        src='/mnt/files/tmp/'+file_info.file_path;
        with open(src, 'wb') as new_file:
           new_file.write(downloaded_file)
        bot.reply_to(message,"Фото добавлено") 

    except Exception as e:
        bot.reply_to(message,e )
```