# file_id Telegram bot python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Какой командой можно получить file.id голосового файла?

Comment: [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1305337/234134) как получить `file_id` отправленного пользователю файла на примере `sendDocument`. [а здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/615794/234134) как сохранить присланный файл боту (там же есть и получение `file_id`)

Answer (score -1):

вы имеете ввиду ID файла в операционной системе (ОС)? Тогда укажите какая ОС.
Общепринятая практика - получить уникальный ID  путем вычисления хэш суммы (контрольной суммы) файла. Это алгоритм, который на основе содержимого файла выдает уникальное число. Для этого хорошо подойдет библиотека `haslib`

```
import hashlib
file = path_to_file
with open(file,"rb") as f:
    bytes = f.read()
    readable_hash = hashlib.md5(bytes).hexdigest()
    print(readable_hash)
```