# Telegram API. Бот не отправляет второй раз документ в чат

Tags: python, django, post, telebot

Суть проблемы:

Я делаю бота для отправки сообщения в чаты, отправляется три сообщения(в один чат) `name`, `document`, `msg` при первой отправке отправляются все три сообщения, при отправке в остальные чаты отправляются name, msg, но document не отправляется
Прилагаю код(токены и id чата специально убрал для вопроса)(эти 3 респонса находятся в цикле for который проходится по списку с id чатов и вставляет их в параметры запроса):

```
            document = request.FILES['document']

            response = requests.post(
                url='https://api.telegram.org/token/sendMessage',
                data={'chat_id': chat_id, 'text': request.POST["name"]}
            ).json()

            response = requests.post(
                f'https://api.telegram.org/token/sendDocument',
                data={'chat_id': chat_id},
                files={"document": document}
            ).json()

            response = requests.post(
                url='https://api.telegram.org/token/sendMessage',
                data={'chat_id': chat_id, 'text': request.POST["msg"]}
            ).json()
```

P.S. Если это важно, часть представления у меня в проекте Django

P.S.2. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: имеется ли ошибка? нельзя отправить одно сообщение, документ, с caption?

Comment: @Violet, В том то и дело, не ошибок ничего, просто респонс приходит который я задал
На счёт одного сообщения, я просто не знаю как это реализовать, был бы очень благодарен, если бы ты помог мне с этим, может быть такое сработает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

для отправки документа с подписью (caption) укажите это в `data`:

```
response = requests.post(f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{bot_token}/sendDocument', data={'chat_id': 123, 'caption': '123'},
                         files={"document": 'https://telegram.org/img/SiteiOS.jpg'}).json()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

для получения информации об отправленном сообщении достаточно выполнить

```
print(response.json())
>>> {'ok': True, 'result': {'message_id': 5834, 'from': {'id': 995, 'is_bot': True, 'first_name': 'violet', 'username': 'violet'}, 'chat': {'id': 123, 'first_name': '', 'last_name': 'Violet', 'username': 'Violet', 'type': 'private'}, 'date': 1626296135, 'document': {'file_name': 'document', 'file_id': 'BQACAgIAAxkDAAIWymDvT0f40hbaHsGfaYE5s9lOlyOcAAK7DQAC82qAS0iXZRrvOJqAIAQ', 'file_unique_id': 'AgADuw0AAvNqgEs', 'file_size': 36}, 'caption': '123'}}
```

для получения `file_id`:
`print(response.json()['result']['document']['file_id'])`

[send document](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#senddocument)

Comment: Опять же приходит лишь одно сообщение, думаю это как-то связанно с тем что я использую sendDocument

Comment: вы заменили три `post` запроса на один в `caption` в котором `name` и `msg`?

Comment: Да, я прикрепил фото с кодом который я запускаю

Comment: может быть можно как-то хотя бы ошибку получить почему они не отправляются (Если что я проверил список чатов их 3 а отправляется в один)

Comment: выведите `print(response.content)` там будет информация об отправке запроса

Comment: Вот что выдаёт мне : {'ok': False, 'error_code': 400, 'description': 'Bad Request: file must be non-empty'}

Comment: это говорит о том, что файл отправляемый в запросе пуст или не указан. попробуйте отправлять последующие (после первого) файлы с помощью `file_id`

Comment: Спасибо, тебе большое
Если интересно вот как написал с твоей помощью:https://skr.sh/s92n6uYLwEN

Comment: @Den, пожалуйста, и не забудьте [проголосовать и принять ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: репутации не хватает конечно чтобы проголосовать, но я отметил как правильный ответ, ещё раз спасибо, ты отличный человек!

Comment: что-то меня смущает в вашем решении из скриншота. `отправить файл` `если ОК` `получить file_id` `иначе отправить с помощью file_id`. получается что если при первой отправке документа как файла будет `не ок`, то и последующие не отправятся т.к. не будет `file_id` или у меня глаз уже замылен..

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127518/discussion-between-violet-and-den).