# Скачивание файла в PyTelegramBotAPI

Tags: python, telebot

У меня есть код, который должен принимать файл и скачивать его на сервер

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['document'])
def download_file(message):
    file_name = message.document.file_name
    file_id = message.document.file_name
    file_id_info = bot.get_file(message.document.file_id)
    downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_id_info.file_path)
    src = file_name
    with open("files/" + src, "wb") as new_file:
        new_file.write(downloaded_file)
```

Но выпадает такая ошибка

> downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_id_info.file_path)       AttributeError: 'AsyncTask' object has no attribute 'file_path'

Как необходимо правильно сохранять файлы?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/615794/234134

Answer (score 0):

```
link = "images/Название файла" + ".jpg"
with open(link, "wb") as save_file:
    save_file.write(bot.download_file(bot.get_file(message.photo[-1].file_id).file_path))
```

Вот рабочий вариант кода, сам его использую во всех проектах, в которых он нужен.