# Присвоить имя при отправлении файла

Tags: python, telebot, загрузка

Пишу бота для расписания, можно сказать новичок в python. Использую telebot в телеграмм и возникла такая вот загвоздка: Мне требуется, чтобы при отправлении файла в телеграмм бот, сам бот загрузил этот файл и дал ему конкретное имя. У меня же телеграмм присваивает ему file_id, а мне нужное конкретное имя. Что-то нашел для загрузки файла, но это недостаточно

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
def handle_docs_photo(message):

    try:


        file_info = bot.get_file(message.photo[len(message.photo)-1].file_id)
        downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)

        src='Replaces/'+file_info.file_path
        with open(src, 'wb') as new_file:
           new_file.write(downloaded_file)
        bot.reply_to(message,"Фото добавлено") 

    except Exception as e:
        bot.reply_to(message,e )
```

Comment: отправка пользователю файла или загрузка от пользователя?

Comment: загрузка от пользователя

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/615794/234134