# Как обработать .wav или mp3 файлов в телеграмм боте

Tags: python, telegram-bot

хочу создать бота в телеграмм, который может получать аудиофайлы разных типов, производить с ними некоторые манипуляции и возвращать пользователю что-то (например фото) как именно с помощью telebot (именно этот API я хочу использовать) возможно это реализовать. Либо может кто-то может оставить ссылку на конкретный пример.Заранее спасибо
UPD
код:

```
import telebot
import numpy as np
from numpy import argmax
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#%matplotlib inline
import librosa
import librosa.display
#import IPython.display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
bot = telebot.TeleBot('00000')
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['document','audio'])
def handle_docs_photo(message):
    try:
        chat_id = message.chat.id

        file_info = bot.get_file(message.document.file_id)
        downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)

        src = 'C:\\Users\\NitghtWay\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\Botyara\\' + message.document.file_name;
        with open(src, 'wb') as new_file:
            new_file.write(downloaded_file)

        bot.reply_to(message, "Пожалуй, я сохраню это")
    except Exception as e:
        bot.reply_to(message, e)
bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/615794/234134

Comment: @bot.message_handler(content_types=['document','audio']) изменил вот эту строчку, бот не сохраняет и вместо нормального ответа говорит:'NoneType' object has no attribute 'file_id'

Comment: приведите свой код и ошибку через [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1355405/edit)

Comment: Привел код в правке, он принимает любые файлы, кроме audio (mp3, или wav не работает)

Answer (score 1):

- информация о типе контента содержится в `message.content_type`
- информация о файле хранится, в вашем случае, в `message.document` и `message.audio`
- для wav `content_types=['document']`
- для mp3 `content_types=['audio']`

таким образом:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['document', 'audio'])
def get_file(message):
    try:
        if message.content_type == 'document':  # wav
            print(message.document)

            file_info = bot.get_file(message.document.file_id)
            downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)

            src = 'files/' + message.document.file_name
            with open(src, 'wb') as new_file:
                new_file.write(downloaded_file)

            bot.reply_to(message, "Пожалуй, я сохраню это")
        elif message.content_type == 'audio':  # mp3
            print(message.audio)

            file_info = bot.get_file(message.audio.file_id)
            downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)

            src = 'files/' + message.audio.file_name
            with open(src, 'wb') as new_file:
                new_file.write(downloaded_file)

            bot.reply_to(message, "Пожалуй, я сохраню это")
    except Exception as e:
        bot.reply_to(message, str(e))
```

для Windows можно использовать пути вида `files/` при условии, что каталог `files` находится рядом с файлом `.py`

Comment: Если ответ решает вашу задачу, пожалуйста не забудьте [проголосовать и принять ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) :)